# SQLite replacing data in existing column

Tags: sqlite

Really new to SQLite and have a basic question that would help me a lot. If I have a table that looks like this:

```
_id   NAME
1     Mark
2     Bob
```

Let's say that I do an insert statement in to row 2 and put the name John. Will the table look like this:

```
_id   NAME
1     Mark
2     John
```

Or would I have to query the database, see if row 2 already contains a name, if it does, replace it with John? In other words, it doesn't automatically replace what's there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a simple 'Find and Replace" in MsSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044/how-do-i-do-a-simple-find-and-replace-in-mssql)

Comment: AFAIK the `INSERT` statement and the `UPDATE` statement are different.

Comment: So what happens when using an INSERT statement in to a column that already has data there. Does it simply not do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's basically 3 ways to change table contents:

- INSERT: this will always **add** a new row to the table
- UPDATE: this will **change** existing rows in the table
- DELETE: this will **remove** existing rows in the table

Lets say that your table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    _id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and already contains this data:

```
_id NAME
1   Mark
2   Bob
```

if you then run

```
INSERT INTO test (Name) VALUES ('John')
```

then the table will look like this:

```
_id NAME
1   Mark
2   Bob
3   John
```

Note that you could also have done:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES( 3, 'John' )
```

but then you would have to know that `3` is the next available number in the `_id` column.

If instead you want to **change** the `Name` of the row with `_id` 2, you would run this query:

```
UPDATE test SET Name='John' WHERE _id = 2
```

Comment: What if your _id is a PRIMARY KEY and you INSERT in to a column using an existing _id value? For example, INSERT in to column 2(PRIMARY KEY) with the name John. Let's say that column already has a name there (Bob) but you use INSERT to put another name (John). Will a new row still be created or nothing will happen?

Comment: FIrst, you don't insert into columns, you insert a row into a table. But, you will get an error - a PRIMARY KEY must be unique. If however you leave out the `PRIMARY KEY(id)` from the table definition, then you will get a new row with `2, 'John'` (and the old row with `2, 'Bob'` will still be there).

I strongly suggest you search for 'sql introduction' (there's even youtube videos) and brush up on the basics so you get the terminology straight.