# SQL query for FIND and REPLACE with if condition

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, replace, find

Is it possible to make a query like that so I get the desired result in MySQL?

I want to find and replace values: under table post_meta and in post_value ".../folder/..." to "..../events/...." if parent_post = = 342. Can any one help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a simple 'Find and Replace" in MsSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044/how-do-i-do-a-simple-find-and-replace-in-mssql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for this

```
UPDATE post_meta
SET post_value = REPLACE(post_value, '/folder/', '/events/')
WHERE parent_post = 342
```

Comment: @NagaRaj . . . Thank yous are nice.  Accepting the answer is much, much better.