# Find and replace or delete part of string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, replace

I have a dataset in sql and I would like to remove certain part of the data

I have searched online and found that find and replace could be used for what I want but being fairly new to sql I am not sure if I am approaching it correctly

`SELECT REPLACE('SQL Tutorial', 'T', 'M');`

[How do I do a simple 'Find and Replace" in MsSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044/how-do-i-do-a-simple-find-and-replace-in-mssql)
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp

To keep things simple, here is a sample of the dataset

column name userdetails:
`[{value={ "name":"Alice", "id":"69", "status": "active"}}]`

I want to remove `[{value=` from the start of the data and `}]` from end of the data. The end goal is to have this:

`{ "name":"Alice", "id":"69", "status": "active"}`

This is how I am trying to approach it:

`SELECT * FROM REPLACE("mytable",'[{value=','');`

Actual: `[{value={ "name":"Alice", "id":"69", "status": "active"}}]`

expected: `{ "name":"Alice", "id":"69", "status": "active"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `SELECT SUBSTR(NAME_OF_THE_COLUMN, 8, LENGTH(NAME_OF_THE_COLUMN)-9) FROM NAME_OF_THE_TABLE` you'll remove the first 8 characters and the last 2 characters, which is the desired result, I guess.

---

Example: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_substr2) you can play with it. Example:

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm "mytable" is name of the table and not string - sorry for confusion

Comment: How do I say which table I want to reach?

Comment: I changed the name with `NAME_OF_THE_COLUMN` and added the `NAME_OF_THE_TABLE`

Comment: no luck, it gives 'line 1:10: mismatched input 'substr' expecting {<eof>, ',', 'from', 'where', 'group', 'order', 'having', 'limit', 'union', 'except', 'intersect'}'

Comment: sorry, there was one parenthesis `)` that had to be removed. Try again

Comment: no worries, made some progress :) now it gives - SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:29: Unexpected parameters (array(row(message varchar))) for function length. Expected: length(char(x)) , length(varchar(x)) , length(varbinary)

Comment: Inside LENGTH you have to write the name of one single column, not all the columns. Could you please show the structure of your table, please?