# Multiple find and replace using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'd like to use an SQL query to find and replace multiple values. I've had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59044/609630) question that shows the following answer:

```
UPDATE 
    YourTable
SET 
    Column1 = REPLACE(Column1,'a','b')
WHERE 
    Column1 LIKE '%a%'
```

How can I find and replace multiple values instead of just the one?

My data is like the following, there's hundreds of rows, I'm specifically wanting to target each `product_id:123`:

> subscription_id,products
> "128","product_id:268|quantity:1|total:3.15|meta:|tax:0;product_id:267|quantity:1|total:2.97|meta:|tax:0"

I need to replace the product id's with new products id's. So it'll be "everything matching 268 will become 195" and "everything matching 267 will become 194".

Is there an efficient way to do it other than taking the code block above and using that for each product. Can I be done with one sweep through?

Comment: Unquestionably outside the scope of the question as you've posed it, but you really, *really* need to normalize your table structure. The concatenation of data this way isn't scalable/sustainable/reliable.

Comment: @esqew All this data is going into an importer and then separated out... it's horrible but that's how it accepts the data.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest possible way would be to chain `REPLACE`s together, but considering the concatenated nature of the field you need to be sure you don't inadvertently target something that's not actually a `product_id` value. You can mitigate this by including some contextual content from the string value itself:

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET products = REPLACE(REPLACE(products, "product_id:267|", "product_id:194|"), "product_id:268|", "product_id:195|");
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hso1YkTvAVX62cbJbR8YAZ/0) | [MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual :: 13.2.8 `REPLACE` Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html)

---

If there's some variability in how these strings might appear in a given field and you're running MySQL >=8.0, you can leverage something like [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) to perform this same replacement using a defined RegExp pattern.

Comment: Great thanks. Just for my understanding, if I wanted to add more would it be 

`SET products = REPLACE(REPLACE(products, "product_id:267|", "product_id:194|"), "product_id:268|", "product_id:195|", "product_id:111|", "product_id:222|");`?

Comment: Unfortunately not with this method, you'd need to properly chain a single `REPLACE` for each value you need to replace with each of the three required parameters; what you've got here in your comment wouldn't be valid syntax. You'd need something more akin to  `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(products, "product_id:267|", "product_id:194|"), "product_id:268|", "product_id:195|"), "product_id:111|", "product_id:222|");`. Be sure to review [the documentation for `REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html)

Comment: This is certainly a solution, but I do not really think it's simple. If you have 10 000 of values, then you put 10 000 function calls on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways. For example, you can create a table like

replacements(id, oldval, newval)

and do the following:

```
UPDATE
    Yourtable
JOIN
    replacements
ON
    Yourtable.Column1 LIKE CONCAT('%', replacements.oldval, '%')
SET
    Yourtable.Column1 = REPLACE(Yourtable.Column1, replacements.oldval, replacements.newval);
```

The problem is that you would need to fill replacements with the pairs of oldval-newval, but MySQL cannot guess that. Insertion is as simple (assuming that id is auto_increment) as

```
INSERT INTO replacements(oldval, newval) VALUES
('a', 'b'),
('c', 'd'),
...
;
```